# What is the fraction of customers lost in a finite queue with one server, M/M/1/k? k = four places and s = 1 server

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

> What is the fraction of customers lost in a finite queue with one server, M/M/1/k? $k =$ four places and $s = 1$ server

$k=4, \lambda=\dfrac 1 {30}$, $\mu=\dfrac 1 {25}$

The steady-state probs are p0 = 0.2786, p1 = 0.2322, p2 = 0.1935, p3 = 0.1612, p4 = 0.1343. The theory says that a client doesn't do the queue if the system is in state 4. Thus the portion of clients won´t join the queue is p4. is that correct?

Comment: Again, please provide the answers to these questions **in the body of your question**.  It will better avoid downvotes and close votes in this way.

Comment: That's it, Brain Tung, could you answer my question?

Comment: Well, I would, but Daniel S has already done that admirably, I think.  The biggest takeaway is PASTA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are right, Luis.  Many people get confused on that one.

The steady state probabilities are the probabilities that a client arrives in the system to find the system at that state.

In particular, $p4$ is the probability that an arrival finds the system at state $4$ and is rejected.

Hence, the answer is simply $p4$.

This is due to PASTA (Poisson Arrivals See Time Averages)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_theorem